# Bilateral assignment/declaration in MATLAB or Python

Tags: python, matlab

Is there a declaration/assign function in MATLAB or Python which works in both ways, bilateral/mirror type of use?
Example;

```
x = 3
print x
#output is 3#
```

but what if there is a type of function, like this;

```
x _=_ 3
print x
# output is 3 #
print 3
# output is x #
```

Comment: Most languages don't support that sort of thing. You may find this article helpful: [Facts and myths about Python names and values](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html), which was written by SO veteran Ned Batchelder.

Comment: OTOH, there _is_ a way in Python to find all names in the current local or global scope that are bound to a particular object, but it's _not_ the sort of thing you do in a normal program. :)

Answer (score 3):

In Python, no. In Matlab, probably no. What your asking for doesn't even really make sense. How can you assign `x`, a name, to `3`, an integer literal? You can't assign anything to an integer literal, anyway! And what do you mean by x? The string `"x"`? The functionality you are probably looking for would be achieved by a [map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array). Essentially, a map is a collection of key, value pairs where you access the value with the key. Keys must be unique, but the same value can have different keys. Python has a built-in data structure called a `dict` for this very purpose:

```
num_to_letter = {1:'x', 2: 'y'}
print(num_to_letter[1])
print(num_to_letter[2])
```

You can choose whether to contain the reverse mapping in the same `dict` or make another dict for that purpose.

```
letter_to_num = {}
for key in num_to_letter:
    letter_to_num[num_to_letter[key]] = key

print(letter_to_num)
```

Once you get used to python, you can start using dictionary comprehensions in python 3:

```
letter_to_num = {v:k for k,v in num_to_letter.items()}
```

In python 2, you will have to use the following:

```
letter_to_num = dict((v,k) for k,v in num_to_letter.items())
```

Comment: Python 2.7 supports the dict comprehension syntax.

Comment: Yes, a string, a word, set of characters, but not a variable, in a way that at the same time `string = integer` and  `integer = string`. So for example; when sorted by integer in a matrix, i could `print` their respective string in the same order as integer sorted.

Comment: @Lindy The simple way to do that kind of thing is to make a list of (name, integer) tuples. You can sort such a list alphabetically or numerically.

Answer (score 2):

That would be trying to set the value of a literal like it was a variable, which you can't do. The number 3 cannot be the name of a variable with the value of "x", nor can it be an alias to a variable as far as I know.

Answer (score 1):

In MATLAB, no. You can use only lower and uppercase letters as the start of a variable name.

Answer (score 0):

BIG NO.

Check out python variable name rules in Google

You cannot assign anything to a number and make it a variable.

Another reason is making a number a variable is allowing to vary it's value. Ideally 3 should be always 3

Almost in all modern languages, a number cannot be used as a variable.